# Turning strings into lists of items in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | I am a student. |
| 2 | We have a house. |
| 3 | Hello. |
| 4 | I live in NY City. |

I want to turn the sentences into lists (so ['I','am','a','student','.'] etc) while still preserving the dataframe.

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ['I','am','a','student','.'] |

I have found ways to extract the rows and transform them into lists, but all those methods require either making a separate dataframe or a list of lists...

Comment: Have you tried ```df[new_column_name] = df[column_name].str.split('\s+')```?

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you need:

```
df[columnname] = str(df[columnname]).replace("."," .").split(" ")
```